# How to fetch all database records with a blob image in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am fetching from mysql database student information and it is printed well in array wraped in json encode , but in the student records when i include image i get nothing on the screen where what i need is to get all records with an image of each record . please help me . 
[The results which come out when photo is not include in sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbwed.png)

My code is as follow when i include picture in sql query which gives nothing on the screen :

```
   public function StudentsOfParent($mobile){

 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT
                         a.id,
                         a.name, 
                         a.mobile, 
                         c.id as sutdentId, 
                         c.user_id, 
                         c.full_name, 
                         c.school, 
                         c.level,
                         c.year,
                         c.photo,
                         d.id as busId,                   
                         d.bus_name as plate_no,
                         e.id as DriverId,                           
                         e.driverphone_number,                          
                         e.driver_fullname                          
                         from users a 
                         join students c 
                         on a.id = c.user_id
                         join buses d 
                         on c.id = d.student_id
                         join drivers e
                         on e.id = d.driver_id where a.mobile= ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $mobile);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {

   $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $usersArr = array();
    while ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $usersArr[] = $user;
     }
   $stmt->close();
   // echo json_encode($usersArr);
    return $usersArr;

  } else {
return NULL;
  }
}
```

To access the above function i use the following php file :

```
               <?php 
  include './DbHandler.php';
 $db = new DbHandler(); 
 // json response array
 $response = array("error" => FALSE);
  if (isset($_POST['mobile'])){
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
   $usersArr = $db->StudentsOfParent($mobile);
     if ($usersArr != false) { 
   $response["error"]= FALSE;
   $response["user"] = $usersArr;
   echo json_encode($response); 

        }
       else {
       // user is not found with the credentials
       $response["error"] = TRUE;
       $response["error_msg"] = "Sorry we could not find you !";
         echo json_encode($response);
     }
    }
        else {
    // required post params is missing
   $response["error"] = TRUE;
   $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter is missing!";
   echo json_encode($response);
   }
      ?>
```

Comment: This indentation is bordering on total chaos. That's important because it communicates the structure of your code at a glance, something relevant here where many people might not have a lot of time to figure out what you're doing, and also because it helps you spot bugs visually.

Comment: You're also doing triple negation here. That "Sorry we could not find you" clause only kicks in when `$usersArr` is not *not* not true. It'd be a lot simpler to remove the `!= false` part and leave it as a positive test.

Comment: @tadman Thank you but that is not the maim problem, problem is that the 
 code works with text string only and when I try to add in an image (stored as a BLOB) the JSON output disappears completely

Comment: And i tried to add  this line `$usersArr[] = base64_encode($user['photo']);` it fetches image url but text of other columns don't come to screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this solution ,i used the following function and I put BLOB data into an array 
then i wrap/envelop that array to Json_encode  ,finally i reach to my target of 
displaying image BLOB from MySQL . what i am required now is to decode this json array in android.

We can even decode this image on web with :  `echo '<img src="data:photo/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $user['photo'] ).'"/><br/>';`

**This is the working code :**

```
                 public function StudentsOfParent($mobile){

 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT
                         a.id,
                         a.name, 
                         a.mobile, 
                         c.id as sutdentId, 
                         c.user_id, 
                         c.full_name, 
                         c.school, 
                         c.level,
                         c.year,
                         c.photo,
                         d.id as busId,                   
                         d.bus_name as plate_no,
                         e.id as DriverId,                           
                         e.driverphone_number,                          
                         e.driver_fullname                          
                         from users a 
                         join students c 
                         on a.id = c.user_id
                         join buses d 
                         on c.id = d.student_id
                         join drivers e
                         on e.id = d.driver_id where a.mobile= ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $mobile);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {

   $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $usersArr = array();
    while ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $usersArr[] = $user['id'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['name'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['mobile'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['sutdentId'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['user_id'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['full_name'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['school'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['level'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['year'];
    $usersArr[] = base64_encode($user['photo']);   
    $usersArr[] = $user['busId'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['plate_no'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['DriverId'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['driverphone_number'];
    $usersArr[] = $user['driver_fullname'];
   // echo '<img src="data:photo/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $user['photo'] ).'"/><br/>';
  }
   $stmt->close();
   // echo json_encode($usersArr);
    return $usersArr;

  } else {
return NULL;
  }
}
```